# Robocopy problems

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to move a folder from a local disk (D Drive) and move it to our new TrueNAS. Robocopy has worked on some of the directories, but there are two that for some reason I keep getting a "system cannot find the file specified" error for the source directory.

I have googled and read through several articles and none of them have helped. There is one suggestion to install an older version of robocopy but I can not seem to find out how to do that. Anyone have an idea on how to install a different/older verison of robocopy.

I am running it on a 2012 R2 server. The robocopy command I am running is this.

robocopy "D:\files\Artwork" "\ip-address\Omaha-Files\Artwork" /e /b /maxlad:1825 /J /R:1 /W:3 /MT /FP /FFT /LOG+:c:\temp\robocopy.log /NP

I have admin permissions, I am running the command from an administrative powershell console, I have also tried an admin command prompt. Same error.

I have also tried running from a standard user but it gives me a different error that says I don't have backup permissions.

Any help here would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: To be specific, this is the error message in the logs

2022/04/24 19:34:30 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Destination Directory D:\files\Artwork\
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: please add that error msg to your Question. they are hard to find when buried in the comments ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

I added the /nodcopy parameter and this has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a file appearing & disappearing?

- Use "/Z" instead of "/B" and add more retries and maybe longer wait to make it wait for the missing file to reappear.
- Try adding "/L" to do a "no-op" and see what would be copied.
- Maybe add "/XJ" to exclude junction points.

Comment: No luck with /Z or /XJ but when I ran /L it successfully listed every directory and file inside the location. Didn't transfer obviously, but it listed all of them. I just don't understand what's going on here.